# addEventListener: Why can't I replace "mousedown" with "keydown"?

Tags: javascript

New to JS, I got a function like this

```
cvs.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    some_game_state_change_operation();
});
```

And I would like to have this mouse control operation changed to keyboard control:

```
cvs.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    some_game_state_change_operation();
});
```

Now whatever key I press, nothing happens. Function `some_game_state_change_operation()` is never executed. Why?

A possible relevant line:

```
function render(gameState) {
    render.cvs = document.getElementById("cvs");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me... Is  your `some_game_state_change_operation` doing something to prevent keyboard input?

Comment: what type of element is `cvs`?

Comment: The update doesn't explain what type of element `cvs` is... my guess is it is a `canvas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing cvs is a canvas, which you can't focus with the cursor.  Attach the keydown listener to window instead of cvs.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    some_game_state_change_operation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `cvs` is a `canvas`, it can not be focused on unless you add a `tabindex` to it, in which case your `keydown` event listener will work when the canvas is focused on. A `tabindex` of `-1` will allow your `canvas` to be focused on, but will not be in the tabbing order.

```html
<canvas id="cvs" tabindex="-1" height="50" width="100" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
document.getElementById("cvs").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "KeyCode: "+e.keyCode+" Key: "+e.key;
});
</script>
```